# What is the proper way to cite the Packhum corpus?

Tags: text-corpus, packhum-corpus

The PHI Latin corpus (previously known as PHI5.3 and now [available to search online](https://latin.packhum.org/)) is certainly an important tool, and I've made good use of it in various corpus analyses.

However, I'm not sure how to properly reference and cite it. The main page just says that it's "A Resource Prepared by The Packard Humanities Institute", and the About page doesn't have much more; searching online for "packhum latin citation" doesn't turn up much.

If I want to give a proper reference to this corpus, how would I do it? Is there a paper introducing it that can be cited, or an "author" (implementor?) to reference by name? Or should I just credit it all to "The Packard Humanities Institute"?

Comment: Two questions to clarify: (1) Do you mean citations in the context of a scientific article? In many other contexts something less formal would do. (2) Have you tried reaching out to the email address `latin@packhum.org` give on their pages? I would assume that they have the definitive answer. Having their answer recorded here on our site would be great.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Ah yes, I mean in the context of a publication. Their very minimal license agreement doesn't even indicate whether that's allowed, but going from the earlier licensing on their CDs, it seems like the intent is to allow pretty much any academic use (just not commercial publication), so I'm hoping that's allowed. I'll send them an email and update here if I get a response!

Comment: (In the meantime, though, if anyone else knows of precedent, I'm sure there are papers out there which have used this corpus and have probably cited it _somehow_.)

Answer (score 1):

**Finding the Publication Date:**

Enter the URL into the browser preceded by 'inurl:'

> inurl:https://latin.packhum.org/search

After accessing that page, add '&as_qdr=y15' to the end of the URL:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Flatin.packhum.org%2Fsearch&rlz=1C1ASVC_pt-BRBR908BR908&oq=inurl%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Flatin.packhum.org%2Fsearch&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l2j69i58.1365j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&as_qdr=y15

The date of publication will appear in the search results:

[image]

**APA Format:**

For entire website:

> The Packard Humanities Institute. (2011, July 15). *PHI Latin Texts*.
> Retrieved from https://latin.packhum.org/

For a particular page, the title of the page is required (in the example 'Word Search'). The publication date and URL should also pertain to the page in question:

> The Packard Humanities Institute. (2011, September 28). Word Search.
> *PHI Latin Texts*. Retrieved from https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=scapula

**MLA Format:**

Notice that the month is abbreviated in the publication date:

> The Packard Humanities Institute. *PHI Latin Texts*. 15 Jul. 2011:
> https://latin.packhum.org/

For a particular page:

> The Packard Humanities Institute. "Word Search". *PHI Latin Texts*. 28
> Sep. 2011: https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=scapula

**Harvard Format:**

The Harvard format only requires the year of publication, but, in addition to that, the date accessed is required:

> The Packard Humanities Institute. (2011). PHI Latin Texts [Online].
> Available at: https://latin.packhum.org/ (Accessed: 21 December 2020).

For a particular page:

> The Packard Humanities Institute. (2011). *Word Search* [Online]. PHI
> Latin Texts. Available at: https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=scapula
> (Accessed: 21 December 2020).

Comment: Very nice! In this particular case, I know from outside information that this version of the data was first published (on CD) in 1991, and then moved online 20 years later; I'm assuming I should cite when the data was first published in _any_ form, rather than when it was moved online, since that's what I'd do with a digitized article or book?

Comment: @Draconis. I don't know. My [source](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/web-citation-guide) simply said to cite the date when it was published on the internet. The instructions I included are those that they gave for obtaining that.